# Viewport scale in react-native-webview keep fontsize of header

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, scale, viewport

I am working on an app that will have web content, living in a web view, and some other content and views built using react-native. I have a meta tag viewport with config user scalable is yes.

But my problem is I want when I zoom my web view, some span have content HTML not zoom out with another content and that text keeps current size. I found an example in the mail app detail view in Gmail.

Thanks!

[image: expample]

In zone 1, this text does not change the font when zoom,

In zone 2, content zoom out
[image: this is my code HTML]

[image: and this is my library WebView]

Comment: Does nobody helps me?

Comment: please, provide an example app with minimal working code.

Comment: @KiênTrầnTrung, I want to help you but it is not possible, because your question information is not enough, even the main desire is not clear. who an example by using GIF image or I don't know some screenshots with more detail.

Comment: I just add a more image.

Comment: @KiênTrầnTrung please can you provide some code in text form, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you are asking for.

If you use GMail on a mobile device, zooming in will cause the email to zoom in, but not the header of the email. However, if you zoom in on the header itself, it will zoom in at that point.

What you are looking for is how to handle multi-touch interactions.

GMail does this by preventing the default behavior of the zoom in when zooming on a target element. In this case, the email body.

When zooming in on the header, it is no longer preventing the default behavior.

It's not a trivial thing to implement. You'll need to take some time to read up on multi-touch interactions. You can find great info over at MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Multi-touch_interaction

Comment: In your opinion, I would be better off removing the viewport from the meta tag and satisfying the zoom action of the content based on multi-touch interactions. right?

I think It posible

Comment: @KiênTrầnTrung definitely leave the viewport tag in there. You can satisfy the zoom action while still using the viewport tag. Just don't set a maximum scale and you'll be golden.